# Google SDTT giving "The URL is unreachable" error even when response status is 200

Tags: google-rich-snippets-tool

#### The issue

I have this site that I've recently added some JSON+LD data to. I wanted to verify that, so I ran the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool). When I put in my site, I get an error saying:

> The URL is unreachable. Ensure robots.txt is accessible and the server is responding with a 200 status code.

#### Things I've tried so far

1) Checked the site on https://crossbrowsertesting.com/, and it's rendering fine in all major browsers.

2) Added a log to see if app is indeed throwing some error, the code:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "sdtt.log");
    string headers = String.Empty;
    foreach (var key in Response.Headers.AllKeys)
        headers += key + "=" + Response.Headers[key] + ";";
    File.AppendAllText(file, DateTime.Now.ToString())
    File.AppendAllText(file, "_" + Response.Status);
    File.AppendAllText(file, "_" + headers);
}
```

After that, I ran the SDTT again and got this in my log:

```
4/28/2018 5:08:56 PM_200 OK_Server=Microsoft-IIS/8.5;
4/28/2018 5:09:26 PM_200 OK_Server=Microsoft-IIS/8.5;
```

As you can see, it is returning 200 status.

3) In the console window, in Chrome developer tools (one that opens up when you press F12), in the network tab, I verified that when I click submit on SDTT, the response, as shown in the network tab, is indeed 200. Here's the screenshot attached.

[image]

Even that is showing that the site is returning the status 200.

---

When everything is returning 200, I am not sure what exactly is causing the issue and why is the SDTT is saying URL is unreachable.

Comment: *The URL is unreachable.* This happens from time to time. As long as your site is working there is nothing to freak out about. Try again later.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks, man! You just saved me from my headache. This thing was driving me crazy!